# How to hide an element if another element exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button with classname **ADD** to create an i-frame.

when clicked on add I would like to hide the button if that iframe creates. is there a way to hide div with classname : add after iframe creation?

Here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframeplace').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframeplace").html("<iframe name='someFrame' id='someFrame' width='560' height='315'></iframe>");
    }, 3000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div class="ADD">ADD</div>
</a>
<div id="iframeplace"></div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of more helpful and interesting questions which are not even getting upvoted once and this, trivial one got 7 upvotes. Hillarious.

Comment: If something like this is not a duplicate, it's bound to be helpful to many. Trivial isn't trivial for a beginner.

Comment: @JollyJoker Yes, but upvotes are for questioning quality, not the question itself. "How to cure cancer" (on a appropriate SE site) would not be a good question, because even though it would be helpful to many, there was no research or previous attempt to do so. But this misconception (or reflex) is unfortunately very widespread throughout the network, not just this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `.length` which returns the number of elements for the specified selector. In your case the selector would be `#iframeplace`.

How you will hide the item is completely up to you - you can either use jQuery `hide` method or hide it using the CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframeplace').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframeplace").html("<iframe name='someFrame' id='someFrame' width='560' height='315'></iframe>");
    }, 3000);
    
    if($('#iframeplace').length == 1)
    {
        $(".adding").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div class="ADD">ADD</div>
</a>
<div id="iframeplace"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say which style `a` and nested `div` have, so you can hide either `a` with class name `adding` or `div` with class name `ADD`. Anyway you need to do it after iframe load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframeplace').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframeplace").html("<iframe name='someFrame' id='someFrame' width='560' height='315'></iframe>");
      $(".ADD").css("display", "none");
   }, 3000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div class="ADD">ADD</div>
</a>
<div id="iframeplace"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to hide element in differnt ways by  `.hide()` , `.fadeOut()` ,`.slideUp()`

or by css using `display:none`

If you want the element to keep its space then you need to use,

```
$('.ADD').css('visibility','hidden')
```

If you dont want the element to retain its space, then you can use,

```
$('.ADD').css('display','none')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframeplace').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframeplace").html("<iframe name='someFrame' id='someFrame' width='560' height='315'></iframe>");
      $(".adding").hide();
   }, 3000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div class="ADD">ADD</div>
</a>
<div id="iframeplace"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

Add this condition.

```
 if($( "#iframeplace" ).contents().find( "iframe" )){
    $(".ADD").css('display','none');    
 }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframeplace').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');
    if($( "#iframeplace" ).contents().find( "iframe" )){
      $(".ADD").css('display','none'); 
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframeplace").html("<iframe name='someFrame' id='someFrame' width='560' height='315'></iframe>");
    }, 3000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div class="ADD">ADD</div>
</a>
<div id="iframeplace"></div>
```